# Why is this list not 'saving' after I execute the function?

Tags: python, list

So i've only been coding for a few weeks and today I was messing around writing an algorithm in python that fills an empty list. I wrote this:

```
def wth (a,b):

    list=[]
    i = 0
    j = b
    while len(list)<a:
        list.insert(i,j)
        i=i+1
        j=j+1
    return list
```

It works, for instance:

```
wth(10,10)

[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

However, if I then want to keep this list and do something to it, it just returns to an empty list:

```
print list

[]
```

Why is this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a function ? and where and how you call your list ?

Comment: `if I then want to keep this list and do something to it, it just returns to an empty list:` - Can you please explain this?

Comment: It would appear to be a coincidence that `list` is defined outside the function `wth` and that its value is an empty list.

Comment: Are you sure? `print list` should have printed "<type 'list'>". You may have created a global variable called "list" that masks the built-in list type.

Comment: The short version is: "I want to keep this list" means "I want to assign this list to some variable" (or list member or object attribute or whatever, as long as it's assigned to _something_). That's how you keep things.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the result of a function, you need to assign it to a variable, like this

```
new_list = wth(a, b)
print new_list
```

Instead of all this code, you can simply use, `range` function to do want you want, like this

```
def wth(a, b):
    return range(b, b + a)
```

Comment: @Robᵩ I think I understood his question now. Please check the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

In your example, "list" is a variable in the scope of the function. When the function terminates, the object that "list" points to is returned to the caller, but the "list" variable itself is destroyed along with all variables in the local function context.

It turns out that "list" is the name of a built-in, so when you try to print it later, you should get `"<type 'list'>"`. From your example, I assume you've created a global variable called "list" somewhere along the line.

Its usually unwise to use built-in types or functions as variable names (list, dict, map, etc...) because you mask objects you may want to use later and generally confuse everybody.